# symfony2 - form validation fails: form is always valid

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have these validation rules:

```
Cgboard\SignupBundle\Entity\SignupData
  properties:
    email:
      - NotBlank:~
      - MinLength:3       // not validating neither this nor the rest
    nickname:
      - NotBlank:~
    password:
      - NotBlank:~
    password_repeat:
      - NotBlank:~
```

My entity

```
<?php
namespace Cgboard\SignupBundle\Entity;


class SignupData {
    public $email;
    public $nickname;
    public $password;
    public $password_repeat;
}
```

And my controller:

```
<?php
namespace Cgboard\SignupBundle\Controller\Frontend;

use     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use     Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SignupController extends Controller
{
        ...

        if($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            $form->bind($request);
            if($form->isValid()) {
                $this->save($SignupData);
            } 
        }

         .....   
}
```

Currently `$form->isValid()` always returns `true`.

Comment: which version of symphony are you using, and are you seeing an error or are you just seeing it go though if the data is blank?

Comment: Ei Derick, im using the version 2. I dont see errors, just that the method is Valid is all time passing like if it was returning all the time True.

Comment: Do you really have 2-space (instead of 4) indentation in your validation file? Where exactly is the yaml-file containing the validation-mapping stored and how is it named? btw. did you clear your cache? Does your action have the request as an argument - `yourAction(Request $request)` ? ... provide **all** the necessary code-parts and filepaths needed to reproduce the problem next time please.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the `validation.yml` file is located in `Cgboard/SignupBundle/Resources/config` Directory , as [nifr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832745/nifr) mentioned clear the cache. also try to validate it using the following way to see if its really working

```
    $testobj = new SignupData();

    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($testobj);


    if (count($errors) > 0) {

        return new Response(print_r($errors, true));
    } else {
        return new Response('The testobj is valid! Yes!');
    }
```